# Debugging a slow PyTorch GPU Inference Pipeline on Beam/Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are attempting to use Google Cloud Dataflow to build a simple GPU-based classification pipeline that looks like this: Pub/Sub request comes in with link to a file on GCS → Read data from GCS → Chop up and batch data → Run inference in PyTorch.

[image: Pipeline of 4 steps: read audio, preprocess, run inference, process output]

#### Background

We deploy our pipeline on Dataflow with a custom Docker image adapted from the `pytorch-minimal` [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/dataflow/gpu-examples/pytorch-minimal/Dockerfile).

We ingest Pub/Sub messages and download data audio files from GCS using `pathy`, then chop audio into chunks for classification.

We've adapted Beam's relatively new `RunInference` function. Currently, there is no GPU support for RunInference on Dataflow
(see open issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-13986). Upon building the Beam pipeline locally before deploy to Dataflow, the model initialization step doesn't recognize a CUDA environment and defaults to a CPU device for inference. This configuration gets propagated to the Dataflow execution environment that is properly GPU-enabled. So, we force a GPU device if requested without a CUDA device check. Other than that, the code is the same as the general `RunInference` code: A `BatchElements` operation followed by a `ParDo` that calls the model.

#### Problem

Everything is working-ish, but GPU inference is very slow – much slower than what we can time the same GPU-instance on processing batches on Google Cloud Compute Engine.

We're looking for advice on how to debug and speed up the pipeline. We suspect that the issue might have to do with threading as well as how Beam/Dataflow manages load across the pipeline stages. We kept running into CUDA OOM issues with multiple threads trying to access the GPU in the `ParDo` function. We launch our jobs with `--num_workers=1 --experiment="use_runner_v2" --experiment="no_use_multiple_sdk_containers"` to avoid multi-processing altogether. We saw that this [2021 beam summit talk on using Dataflow for local ML batch inference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yOsiMOgAHY&ab_channel=ApacheBeam) recommended going even further and just using a single worker thread `--number_of_worker_harness_threads=1`. However, we ideally don't want to do this: it's pretty common practice in ML pipelines like these to have multiple threads doing the I/O work of downloading data from the bucket and preparing batches so that the GPU never sits idle. Unfortunately, it seems that there is no way to tell beam to use a certain max number of threads *per stage* (?), so the best solution we could come up with is to protect the GPU with a Semaphore like so:

```
class _RunInferenceDoFn(beam.DoFn, Generic[ExampleT, PredictionT]):
    ...

    def _get_semaphore(self):
        def get_semaphore():
            logging.info('intializing semaphore...')
            return Semaphore(1)

        return self._shared_semaphore.acquire(get_semaphore)

    def setup(self):
        ...
        self._model = self._load_model()
        self._semaphore = self._get_semaphore()

    def process(self, batch, inference_args):
        ...
        logging.info('trying to acquire semaphore...')
        self._semaphore.acquire()
        logging.info('semaphore acquired')
        start_time = _to_microseconds(self._clock.time_ns())
        result_generator = self._model_handler.run_inference(
            batch, self._model, inference_args)
        end_time = _to_microseconds(self._clock.time_ns())
        self._semaphore.release()
        ...
```

We make three odd observations in that setup:

1. Beam always uses the minimum possible batch size we allow; if we specify a batch size of min 8 max 32, it'll always choose a batch size of at most 8, sometimes lower.
2. The inference timed here is still much much slower when allow multiple threads (`--number_of_worker_harness_threads=10`) than when we single-thread (`--number_of_worker_harness_threads=1`). 2.7s per batch vs. 0.4s per batch, both of which are a bit slower than running on compute engine directly.
3. In the multi-threaded setup, we keep seeing occasional CUDA OOM errors despite using a conservative batch size.

Would appreciate any and all debugging guidance for how to make this work! Right now, the whole pipeline is so slow that we have resorted to just running things in batches on Compute Engine again :/ – but there must be a way to make this work on Dataflow, right?

For reference:

- Single-threaded job:
  `catalin-debug-classifier-test-1660143139 (Job ID: 2022-08-10_07_53_06-5898402459767488826)`
- Multi-threaded job:
  `catalin-debug-classifier-10threads-32batch-1660156741 (Job ID: 2022-08-10_11_39_50-2452382118954657386)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying RunInference!

I believe the problems you were encountering have been documented in the following issues. Can you please confirm if this is the case, or if it's different, explain the errors you were getting? We intend to work on those soon.

1. [Map state_dict to the correct device during loading in PytorchModelHandler](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/22712)
2. [Warn user about automatic GPU to CPU conversion](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/22711).

---

> Beam always uses the minimum possible batch size we allow; if we specify a batch size of min 8 max 32, it'll always choose a batch size of at most 8, sometimes lower.

The way that `BatchElements` decides on the size is by "profiling the time taken by (fused) downstream operations". Please see [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/util.py#L610) and [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/util.py#L305) for more information. It could be due to the specific size/nature of your data that creates a certain type of pattern of historical timings that causes this. Curious: are the data in your pipeline very similar?

---

> The inference timed here is still much much slower when allow multiple threads (--number_of_worker_harness_threads=1) than when we single-thread (--number_of_worker_harness_threads=10). 2.7s per batch vs. 0.4s per batch, both of which are a bit slower than running on compute engine directly.

Just to clarify (probably a typo): did you mean "single threads (--number_of_worker_harness_threads=1) than when we multi-thread (--number_of_worker_harness_threads=10)" take 2.7s per batch vs. 0.4s per batch, respectively?

---

Some other questions:

- How big is the model that you are using?
- What types of GPUs have you tried this on?

---

We are currently looking into a similar issue with respect to GPUs and multithreading in the PR of our TensorRT RunInference. Here's a [thread](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/22131#discussion_r940720337) on that discussion. Something we are actively looking into to manage threads is to use `start_bundle` and `finish_bundle`. Please stay tuned on an update on this.

And let me dig into the logs of the job to see what is going on, and get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks, Andy!

On `RunInference`: I don’t think it’s just a [map state_dict issue](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/22712). It’s more that in the sample code you put out, the model handler is getting called on the machine that *launches* the job rather than the machine that *executes* the job and so `cuda_available()` will be false there. I believe the GitHub issue to reference is [this one](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/21438).

Comment: On the data in the pipeline: Yes, they are super similar. Audio files of varying length come in but all get broken down into 10s chunks. All those 10s chunks look the same.

Comment: Model size: The pytorch bin is 380 MB. I haven’t had a chance to check what it expands into in GPU memory, but I don’t imagine that big until we pipe in data. We can comfortably fit a batch size of ~40 with 10s clips on a compute engine machine on a single T4.

Comment: GPUs: We’ve only been using T4s.

Comment: Thanks for the info and clarification on the GPU-> CPU conversion issue. This [PR](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/22795) should address the issue. In this fix, we don't do the conversion during job submission time; Rather, it is now done at execution time.

Comment: Also, this PR addresses another issue with respect to CUDA OOM. I noticed this [issue](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/22811) when testing on A100s. Wrapping the inference with `torch.no_grad():` context seems to help.

Comment: As a note: For the multi-threaded job, I see a pymongo `DuplicateKeyError`.

Comment: We're also investigating into multi-threading w/ GPUs. I'm wondering if the slowdown scales linearly with the number of threads. Have you tried a job w/ just 2 threads, and see what the performance is like? And maybe also test your jobs with the aforementioned [fix](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/22795)?

Comment: Yep, the `DuplicateKeyError` is ours. No worries about that. We have already made the GPU and `torch.no_grad()` improvements that this PR makes. The big issue remaining is the last thing you mention – the GPU + multi-threading piece. As I mentioned, even when we use a semaphore to force just one thread to access the GPU at any one time, inference time goes up a lot. We can try 2 threads, but in general, I would expect that we'll need more than 2 threads for parallel I/O to make sure we always keep the GPU busy.

Comment: Maybe send me an email at catalin@helloello.com and we can jump on a quick video call?

Comment: Catalin, have you made progress on your use case? In order to look into jobs there would need to be a support ticket raised, is this something that you are able to do?